# Auth0 + xamarin authentification issue: Error redeeming code: Unathorized / no description

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, authorization, auth0

I want to login at my xamarin.android application via auth0.
I found [this](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/xamarin/01-login#set-up-the-auth0-callback-url) tutorial that describes it so nice.

But I have problem with obtaining valid `loginResult`.

I double checked all of the steps described at article but have next error:

[image]
[image]

- The code of my app is the same as in the tutorial, so I do not see the point of embedding it.
- I used JsonWebToken Signature Algorithm RS256 (as pointed at
  tutorial).
- I turn on OIDC Conformant (as pointed at tutorial).

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the Domain and api key value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing type of auth0 application to SPA (single page application) solved my problem.
For more info please check this post: [auth0 issue on github](https://github.com/auth0/auth0.js/issues/317)

Also, I deselect `Refresh token` in application `advanced settings -> grand types`